# How to get the DC gain of an active high pass filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, circuit-analysis, filter, gain

**Edit: I think maybe I am confusing terms (it has been a few years since my last electronics class). I am trying to get the expression for the gain of this active filter amplifier circuit in terms of R1 and R2**

So, I am looking at the following circuit from my textbook:

[image]

And I want to know how to calculate \$A_V\$, so I get the transfer function:
$$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}= \frac{-R_2}{R_1 + \frac{1}{sC}}$$
Now for a DC frequency of 0 Hz to get the DC gain, the capacitor acts as an open circuit with infinite impedance, so then \$\frac{1}{sC}\$ tends to infinity, and I feel like that would mean that the DC gain is 0 just by looking at the transfer function! But, as the schematic suggests, it \$A_V= \frac{-R_2}{R_1}\$, implying that when the frequency is 0, then \$\frac{1}{sC}\$ tends to zero. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: As no DC can flow in R1 and C1, delete them and see what you are left with. Hint - disconnect the non-inverting terminal from the common rail and vary it at DC.

Comment: Please, can you explain why do you think that "the schematic suggests Av=-R2/R1" ?

Comment: @LvW the schematic has the gain and the cutoff frequency in it, in a shaded box

Comment: Consider that the expression \$A_V= \frac{-R_2}{R_1}\$ isn't valid for all frequencies. **If** we assume that the capacitor is a **short** for the frequencies of interest, then \$A_V= \frac{-R_2}{R_1}\$ is correct. For much lower frequencies (like DC = 0 Hz) the expression is **incorrect**. The mentioning of "High pass filter" should tell you already that this circuit isn't going to pass DC.

Comment: You may inject input offset but not DC gain

Comment: Use Av=-R2/(R1 + Xc). By inspection you can see that is the correct formula whereas Av=-R2/R1 is only correct where Xc ~ 0, i.e. at HF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DC gain of that circuit is zero. Once the capacitor impedance drops significantly below R1, the gain becomes -R2/R1. That only happens when the input frequency is significantly greater than \$\frac{1}{2\pi f R_1 C}\$ as semi-alluded-to in the picture. Not all web resources are good at explaining everything.

> *I feel like that would mean that the DC gain is 0V*

Gain is not defined in terms of units because it is volts per volt.

Comment: I would say it is 1 as it becomes a follower (admittedly driven from 0V).

Comment: @PeterSmith I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @PeterSmith What is the impedance of capacitor C1 at the input? What will that mean for any DC voltage at the input? Yes, the follower has a DC gain of 1 but there's an AC coupling capacitor as well.

Comment: I edited the gain units, that was a typo and I understand it was incorrect. 
I don't understand why the capacitor impedance would drop? As far as I know, low frequencies going through a capacitor means the impedance would rise?

Comment: *I don't understand why the capacitor impedance would drop?* What is the impedance of a capacitor as a function of frequency? What is the impedance of a capacitor at DC (frequency = 0)?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie \$\frac{1}{jwC}\$ is the capacitor impedance, so as frequency decreases, impedance tends to infinity

Comment: @Bee correct and your initial intuition was also correct.

Comment: @Andyaka okay, your answer just made total sense! just to verify that I'm correct now: this is a high pass filter, meaning the maximum gain will be achieved at frequencies well above the cutoff frequency, when the capacitor impedance is insignificant in comparison to R1 and so the gain turns out to be R2/R1?

Comment: Bee - Correct. Peter Smith - disagree.  The overall gain of the (((circuit))) is not 1 (or -1), because the output is not an image of the input.  The output is 0 V no matter what the DC voltage is at the left side of C1 (Bee - reference designators - YES!).  This is a gain of 0, not 0 dB.  The output is 0 times any (DC) input.

Comment: @Bee entirely correct.